# Electrical Issues 2001 GMC Sierra 5.3L

Tags: electrical, gmc, ignition-switch, sierra

Vehicle is a 2001 GMC Sierra 1500 5.3L Automatic 2 wheel drive.

The 10A fuse in position IGN0 keeps blowing when turning the key before engine cranks.  When the fuse is blown, oil pressure and battery voltage gauges function correctly but all other gauges and shift indicator display 
are non functioning.  If I push in the trip odometer button on the instrument cluster, all gauges and displays work correctly even with the blown fuse.  The transmission will be in be third gear with fuse blown and need to be shifted manually.

I have taken the instrument cluster to a repair facility and it checked out normal.  I have also replaced the ignition switch and harness, but the issue persists.  I have also replaced the mass air sensor and one O2 sensor as the check engine codes indicated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by confirming that 10A is the right size.

Comment: 10A is the correct value.

Comment: Oh well. So much for that idea.